# Navigation bar specific to each view controller like Apple Music

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

How do I have the navigation bar specific to each view controller? On the right side, the navigation bar stays with the view controller, and the left view controller has its own navigation controller. Should I just make a custom transition? Any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: You can hide navigationbar then add navigationbar programmatically or in your storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in your first viewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
}
```

Then add navigationBar in your viewcontrollers from storyboad. Or you can add one in viewDidLoad programmatically

Comment: Giving custom navigation bar has few problems. First, it doesn't change height depending on the device. Second, if I turn on the hotspot mode, the hotspot view cover half of the navigation bar. In other apps, the entire apps goes below the hotspot view.

Comment: When you want a navigationbar specific to each controller thats the only way. You can create function in view controller extension to reuse it in every controller. If this isnt what you want please explain your problem with more detail so i can help you

Comment: @JosephFrancis default navigationbar handles both navigationbar and status bar. Before iphone X status bar was always 20 pt but now it differs from devices. You can create a custom view containing navigationbar and set the height of custom view to height of navigationabr (which is 44) plus height of status bar

Comment: I did what you told me. However, the push segue presents the view controller from bottom to top. I wanted the default, which is right to left (just like in the picture). Also, how do I get the back button like in the picture  with interactive transition?

Comment: @JosephFrancis push segue is different from present modally !! You are not pushing your view controller thats why it comes from bottom.